# Need explanation on "Fatal Error: Call to a member function query() on null...."

Tags: mysql, ajax, leaflet

This question is **almost** answered in a number of places but I am NOT understanding what I'm reading, this is what I'm doing;

I’m creating a bounds:

```
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(<?php echo "$fitBounds" ?>);
```

Pad it out a bit:

```
var padit  = bounds.pad(.075);
```

Then using it to create a ‘where clause’ for MySQL:

```
var str = "WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('POLYGON(("+ JSON.stringify(padit) +" ))'),latlng)";
```

Which becomes:

```
WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('POLYGON(({"_southWest":{"lat":39.129212532500006,"lng":-94.95074410000001},"_northEast":{"lat":39.4400723675,"lng":-94.1795679}} ))'),latlng)
```

Passing it to my PHP via Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'classList.php',
        data: {q: str}, 
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
});
```

classList.php looks like this:

```
$classList = "";
$sql = ("SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(class,'L') SEPARATOR ',') 
                AS class
                FROM poi
              $whereClause
              GROUP BY class
              ORDER BY class  
         ");
            foreach($db_found->query($sql) as $row) {
                $classList .= "$row[class],";
            }
      echo json_encode($classList);
```

This produces the following error on the foreach:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on null in /var/www/html/classList.php on line 36
```

Almost certainly I have multiple issues above but I don't know where they are. Someone please show me.

Comment: How is `$db_found` set? PHP is telling you that it isn't a valid DB connection. Unrelated to the error, the code you're writing is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks @HPierce for catching that.  It's always hard to build example code that reflects the issues. In the PHP program I forgot the require_once for my credential PHP. So doing that did eliminate the Fatal Error part of my issues. The rest are how to make the Ajax call work.